# Change wording of dupehammer tooltip in case of reopen event in revisions list

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, tooltips, dupehammer

Currently when  the Dupehammer is used to reopen a question, the following tooltip is used: ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25534845/revisions))

> Users with the [tag-here] gold badge can single-handedly mark [tag-here] questions as duplicates

Screenshot:

> [image]

This is not ideal in my opinion, and better be changed to something like:

> Users with the [tag-here] gold badge can single-handedly reopen [tag-here] questions that were marked as duplicate

Can this please be done?